# XAML element in other page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a `MainPage.xaml` and `SecondPage.xaml` , MainPage has a xaml `<Grid x:Name="mGrid" />` what I want to do is to set visibility to collapsed when user press a button on SecondPage like:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton1" Click="myButton1_Click" />

private void myButton1_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   mGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Or maybe to send somehow with that button to MainPage and to handle there this. 
to declare public grid in .cs is not an option for me because I've allready have in that Grid alot of objects. I've tryed somethink like:

```
var pointer = new MainPage();
pointer.mGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

but this alloc a new empty grid. I've googled a lot but no results

Comment: Your code `var pointer = new MainPage()` creates a new instance of `MainPage`, not a reference to your existing main page.  You will need to pass a `MainPage` reference to your `SecondPage` when it's created so that it can reference it.  Can you show your code where the two pages are initially created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewmodel that binds to the MainPage.xaml can have a property like

```
private bool _isGridVisible;
    public bool IsGridVisible
    {
        get { return this._isGridVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._isGridVisible)
            {
                this._isGridVisible = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsGridVisible");
            }
        }
    }
```

and bind to the grid as `Visibility="{Binding Path=IsGridVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"`

And pass this viewmodel object to SecondPage.xaml as a constructor value and set `IsGridVisible = false` on button click.

And you can have a generic converter function like the below to convert boolen to visibility.

```
 public class BooleanVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    private const string REVERSE = "Reverse";

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Visibility)) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        // reverse
        if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString().Equals(REVERSE, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return (((bool)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible);
        }
        else
        {
            return (((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to hide controls on page one based on selections made in page two.

The way to think about this is like you are building web pages.

If you have two web pages they don't know about each other. They just exist on the clients machine. They can pass data between each other while navigating but they are, in the end, just statically displayed pages.

So what you want to do is "cache" the settings from page two so that they can be retrieved by page one.

This can be done a number of ways.

If you are only passing a couple variables then you can do it inside the navigation url

"MainPage.xaml?hideButton=true&hideTextblock=false" ect

If you want to pass a ton of settings then I suggest serializing a settings object to the phones storage.

I have written extensively about this topic here on S.O.

You can get a DLL I made and documentation on how to use it [here](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)